# Is there a way to shut a Windows Service Down or perform an action when the PC is shutdown with Fast Startup enabled

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service, shutdown

I have a Windows Service running on Windows 10 that is required to do something to some external Hardware when the PC is shutdown.

I have this working on a PC when a true Shutdown occurs but I've recently discovered some PC's ( possible by default now ) have Windows Fast Start Enabled.

[image: Fast Startup Option Enabled]

In this case OnShutDown() is not called in the service and I can't shutdown the HW correctly. I've implemented the Pre-shutdown technique [here](https://www.atomia.com/2011/11/16/how-to-process-the-preshutdown-event-in-a-managed-windows-service/) but it also isn't called. ( kind of obvious I guess ).

So my question is "Is there a way to do something that would run code in my Service when a Shut-Down with Fast Restart is enabled or is my only route mandating to all users that Fast Startup be disabled?"

Any help here or clarity on my options would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Windows 10, .NET 4.6.1, C#, WCF hosted in Windows Service, x86.

Comment: What happens when the computer experiences sudden power loss, and why can you not re-use whatever you do for that (presumably, some form of startup recovery?) here too?

Comment: In the case when sudden power loss is experienced nothing is currently done. The external hardware will not be damaged but the state it is left in is not desirable.